# How to inspect dom elements which becomes invisible after mouse moves out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to inspect dom structure of video player (like youtube player). Dom elements only visible when mouse is moving and there are nested elements which requires additional events triggered like clicking on subtitle button. I couldn't find any way to get the child nodes of html while moving mouse. Contents are dissappearing so fast before I inspect them.

I tried element states like active hover focus etc. on each dom node didn't work.As far as I understood it detects mouse move event when mouse stops it toggles elements however I tried to dispatch mouse move event on several html elements in console and that method did not toggle dom nodes.

Comment: I feel you, I had the same issue recently. I managed to come up with a solution that only worked in Chrome... If you hover over the element, and then press ALT+TAB (didn't try on a Mac), to switch to a different window that appears **above** the content, you then then press ALT+TAB again until you focus the Inspect Element window. This requires you to have Inspect Element in a separate window. There may be a better way that I am not aware of (something like pausing JavaScript). I wasn't able to get this working in Firefox...

Comment: it does not work for me because I am using mac chrome. I found a way to stop execution you can check out below answers =).

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is I add a break point to the parent element and then I Inpect the element or it's children with debugger pausing the modification of the dom tree.

In Chrome Developer Tools

1. Go to Elements tab
2. Right-click an element you'd like to monitor
3. Select "Break On ...", then choose "Subtree Modification", or "Attributes Modification", or "Node Removal"

Or you could just manually hover over the element and add a break point using 
"Pause / resume script execution" using the following shortcuts

1. F8 or Ctrl+\ (Windows)
2. F8 or Cmd+\ (Mac)

Comment: No I tried that before, it does not work because there are nested elements with different events like. First one gets triggered by mouse move and second one is triggered by clicking on subtitle button. But when I add subtree modification it stops execution after first event occured. Tried second method now but it does not work either.

Comment: I believe click on the subtitle button and then press the `ctrl+\` in chrome developers console. It would pause execution and then you can hover the mouse to inspect each element.

Comment: It does not work because It requires to focus on dev tools and I move mouse pointer to inspector all node's are gone.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is adding a script to stop js execution.

```
/* This will stop execution when we press F12 */
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => { if (e.keyCode === 123) debugger })
```